# To access the oracle database from one machine to another (with LAN)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I installed oracle11g in one machine and also created the database on it.Now I have to access the already created database from another machine(Remote).

Note: In second machine I'm not install anything for oracle.
Both systems are connected with LAN.

I have to install anything for Remote machine(2nd machine)? ( i.e. Instant Client)

Is this possible to connect the oracle database from one machine to another machine?

Answer (score 0):

1) If you want to connect using some third party tool like Toad, SQL Tools etc., then you need to install Oracle Client in 2nd Machine and copy the tnsnames.ora content from your server machine.

2) If you want to use SQL*Plus only, login to the Server machine using SSH or TELNET and then fire sqlplus username/password@database to access oracle.

There can be more options, may be some other person can tell you here.

Comment: thanks san.. If I install oracle client in 2nd machine after that I have to use third party to tool for accessing database?

Comment: Not required, then you can run from command prompt itself from the client machine. Third party tools only provide flexibility to the end use, otherwise you can do almost everything from sqlplus promt.